# Returning a 2D char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I messed around with this enough but I really don't get it.

Here is what I want to do: Take a 2D char array as an input in a function, change the values in it and then return another 2D char array.

That's it. Quite simple idea, but ideas do not get to work easily in C.

Any idea to get me started in its simplest form is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far? What don't you get? How did you attempt to define the 2D array?

Comment: do you know what a `struct` is?

Comment: I just searched 'c 2 dimensional array' on SO, and got plenty of answers. Start there.

Comment: My usual advice: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C will not return an array from a function.

You can do several things that might be close enough:

- You can package your array in `struct` and `return` that. C *will* return `struct`s from functions just fine. The downside is this can be a lot of memory copying back and forth:

  ```
  struct arr {
      int arr[50][50];
  }

  struct arr function(struct arr a) {
      struct arr result;
      /* operate on a.arr[i][j]
         storing into result.arr[i][j] */
      return result;
  }
  ```
- You can return a *pointer* to your array. This pointer must point to memory you allocate with `malloc(3)` for the array. (Or another memory allocation primitive that doesn't allocate memory from the stack.)

  ```
  int **function(int param[][50]) {
      int arr[][50] = malloc(50 * 50 * sizeof int);
      /* store into arr[i][j] */
      return arr;
  }
  ```
- You can operate on the array pointer passed into your function and *modify* the input array in place.

  ```
  void function(int param[][50]) {
      /* operate on param[i][j] directly -- destroys input */
  }
  ```
- You can use a parameter as an "output variable" and use that to "return" the new array. This is best if you want the *caller* to allocate memory or if you want to indicate success or failure:

  ```
  int output[][50];

  int function(int param[][50], int &output[][50]) {
      output = malloc(50 * 50 * sizeof int);
      /* write into output[i][j] */
      return success_or_failure;
  }
  ```

  Or, for the caller to allocate:

  ```
  int output[50][50];

  void function(int param[][50], int output[][50]) {
      /* write into output[i][j] */
  }
  ```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I was just about to ask how to access indices of the array in the struct.

Comment: Your post was more informative, that is why I chose it as the answer. Also thanks a lot to @pmg!

Comment: @pmg's post does detail mechanisms to avoid fixed-size arrays, so bonus point there. :)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot return an array from a function.

You have several options:

- wrap arrays inside structs

```
struct wraparray {
    int array[42][42];
};

struct wraparray foobar(void) {
    struct wraparray ret = {0};
    return ret;
}
```

- pass the destination array, as a pointer to its first element (and its size), to the function; and change that array

```
int foobar(int *dst, size_t rows, size_t cols, const int *src) {
    size_t len = rows * cols;
    while (len--) {
        *dst++ = 42 + *src++;
    }
    return 0; /* ok */
}

// example usage
int x[42][42];
int y[42][42];
foobar(x[0], 42, 42, y[0]);
```

- change the original array

```
int foobar(int *arr, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    size_t len = rows * cols;
    while (len--) *arr++ = 0;
    return 0; /* ok */
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of struct. Thanks. So what do I do to append values to elements of an array that is in a struct? Do I just say ret[0][0], ret[0][1] to actually refer to that indices of array?

Comment: Oh, figured out in the post below. ret.array[i][j] is the answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the variable is declared `struct wrap w;` then you would use `w.array[i][j]`. If it is declared `struct wrap *w;` then you would use `w->array[i][j]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char **foo(const char * const * bar, size_t const *bar_len, size_t len0) {
    size_t i;        
    char** arr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * len0);
    for (i = 0; i < len0; ++i) {
        arr[i] = malloc(bar_len[i]);
        memcpy(arr[i], bar[i], bar_len[i]);
    }
    /* do something with arr */
    return arr;
}
```

Somewhere else in your code:

```
char **pp;
size_t *pl;
size_t ppl;
/* Assume pp, pl are valid */
char **pq = foo(pp, pl, ppl);
/* Do something with pq */
/* ... */
/* Cleanup pq */
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < ppl; ++i)
        free(pq[i]);
    free(pq);
}
```

Because you're passing by-pointer instead of by-value and you want to write to the input array, you have to make a copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example. Tested and works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test(char**,unsigned int,unsigned int);

const unsigned int sz_fld = 50 + 1;
const unsigned int sz_ffld = 10;

int main(void) {
    char fld[sz_ffld][sz_fld];
    for (unsigned char i=0;i<sz_ffld;++i) {
        strcpy(fld[i],"");
    }

    strcpy(fld[0],"one");
    strcpy(fld[1],"two");
    strcpy(fld[2],"three");

    char** pfld = malloc(sz_ffld*sizeof(char*));
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<sz_ffld;++i) {
        *(pfld+i) = &fld[i][0];
    }

    test(pfld,sz_ffld,sz_fld);

    printf("%s\n",fld[0]);
    printf("%s\n",fld[1]);
    printf("%s\n",fld[2]);

    free(pfld);

    return(0);
}

void test(char** fld,unsigned int m,unsigned int n) {
    strcpy(*(fld+0),"eleven");
    strcpy(*(fld+1),"twelve");
    return;
}
```

Note the following:

For compiling, I am using gcc with the C99 option.

I defined the function to include the two sizes information, but I wrote very basic code and am not actually using the information at all, just the strcpy(), so this certainly is not security-safe code in any way (even though I'm showing the "m" and "n" for such facility). It merely shows a technique for making a static 2D char array, and working with it in a function through the intermediate of an array of pointers to the "strings" of the array.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a 2D array to a function as a parameter, you need to explicitly tell it the size of the arrays second dimension

```
void MyFunction(array2d[][20]) { ... }
```

Comment: it is 50x50. but function is not void it should return 50x50 array too.

Comment: Yes, if you're dealing with an actual 2D array (i.e., an array of arrays).  The problem with that is that the dimensions are fixed at compile time.  For reasonable flexibility, you probably want to use dynamically allocated arrays of pointers to emulate 2D arrays (which is a lot more work).

Comment: in that case, use `int[][50] MyFunction(int[][50] array2d) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

The following will do what you want.  it will print "One" and "Ten".  Also note that it is typed to the exact array dimensions of 10 and 8.

```
char my_array[10][8] = 
{
{"One"},
{"Two"},
{"One"},
{"One"},
{"One"},
{"One"},
{"One"},
{"One"},
{"Nine"},
{"Ten"},
};

void foo ( char (**ret)[10][8] )
{
  *ret = my_array;
}

void main()
{
  char (*ret)[10][8];
  foo(&ret);

  printf("%s\r\n", (*ret)[0] )
  printf("%s\r\n", (*ret)[9] )
}
```

The original question was about RETURNING the array, so I'm updating this to show returning a value.  You can't "return an array" directly, but you CAN make a typedef of an array and return that...

```
char my_array[10][8];
typedef char ReturnArray[8];
ReturnArray* foo()
{
  return my_array;
}
```